# Form post security. Making sure it did not come from outside source

Tags: php, security, forms

I have a simple form and want to verify that the posted value came directory from that form and not from an outside source.

```
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="post" id="post" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
 </form>
```

Do I need to store something in the session? A simple example would be extremely helpful. Thanks.

Comment: set a hidden field on the form with a random value thats set on each load but is compared with when the form is submitted, or use a capcha.

Comment: or hide the form with javascript escape so a bot would need to unescape it first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating the form, you could use:

```
<?php
    session_start(); // don't forget that you need to call before output (place first, or use ob_start()
    $_SESSION['formhash'] = md5(date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'2fiaSFI#T8ahugi83okkj');
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="post" id="post" />
<input type="hidden" name="hash" id="hash" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['formhash']; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

You need to check when somebody is posting that the post request has the correct hash. You could use:

```
<?php
    session_start(); // don't forget that you need to call before output (place first, or use ob_start()
    if (isset($_SESSION['formhash']) && isset($_POST['hash']) && $_SESSION['formhash']==$_POST['hash']) {
        // treat $_POST
    }
?>
```

Comment: Well, I could just send the formhash with my hand-crafted request. Forget it, what the OP is asking for is not possible.

Comment: @tex I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The OP asked for a form that made sure that no other form was used. With my example, this becomes possible. Every client must have the correct session cookie together with the form. If you visit an external site, like `example.com` instead of `mywebserver.com`, then any POST request to `mywebserver.com` will be disregarded by the if clause on line 3 in the second code block. If I'm wrong, please explain how in more detail.

Comment: @tex But how would you get the hash? This is basically [CSRF token stuff](http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries), the goal of which is to prevent an *arbitrary* POST request. If the attacker has the ability to go to this form, grab the token, and *then* submit a false request, there are much bigger problems to worry about.

Comment: So I can setup one single token per user and then use that on every form throughout my site? Or does each form need it's own token?

Comment: Also do I need to clear that session token once there is a token match, or do I just leave it in the session until it expires?

Comment: @Dietpixel You could use the same `$_SESSION['formhash']` per session for all forms, if you only set `$_SESSION['formhash']` once, i.e. you need to add an if condition `if (!isset($_SESSION['formhash'])) $_SESSION['formhash'] = md5(date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'2fiaSFI#T8ahugi83okkj')`. You should not clear `$_SESSION['formhash']` in that case.

The other alternative is to use a new `$_SESSION['formhash']` for each form. If so, you should use different `$_SESSION['formhash']` for each form, e.g. `$_SESSION['formhash']['form1']`. You should clear `$_SESSION['formhash']['form1']` after a POST on `form1`.